# Avoid insert/upsert in mongodb when key is null

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, serialization, spring-data

I want to avoid inserting/modifying the key of a document when its value is null or empty.
I am using mongodb version 5 and spring boot data version 2.4.

Example: If I have a model Person with name and surname as attributes, I want to avoid inserting surname key if its value is null or empty string.

Someone suggest me seeing to modify the WritingConverter bean in order to customize the process when POJO is converted to document but I do not know so much.

Any help?

Comment: I am not familiar with spring but can you share the mongo java driver version? Looking at the source code there was no simple config to omit null values before 4.7.0 and requires writing a custom codec or use something like kmongo's jackson based codec and use jackson annotations/config. Since 4.7.0 however it seems to be omitting such fields.

Comment: Behavior I am inferring from this `encodeValue` function: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blame/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/codecs/pojo/PojoCodecImpl.java#L163